# How device receives push notification? - iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I want to ask you guys
How device receives push notification? 
Is our device continuously connected to apple's server?

Many Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 1):

Device does not remain connected. In fact the app might not even be running any more.

The mechanism is as follows:

1. Your application has to register for notifications.
2. When it registers you get a token, which you send to your server.
3. When you wish to send a push notification, your server connects to Apple server and sends a message to the previously registered token.

Simple :)

For more details see:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

Comment: Actually, the device remains connected in order to have notifications delivered 'immediately'. As stated in the docs: "(...) receives notifications over this persistent connection".

Comment: Thank you very much Rengers for your comment. So is this mean our device is connected to apple's server via internet? If there is no internet connection then we won't eb able to receive push notifications?

Comment: For iPhone the notifications are delivered over the telco network (kind of like SMS messages). So only working cellular connections is required. For iPod, wifi connection is required for push messages to be delivered.

Comment: @Maria Zverina can u please give apple document link where apple talk about "telco network"